# Bad Certificate in TomEE when using Dispatching

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, apache-tomee

I'm having a weird problem with TomEE when I try to call a Webservice behind an HTTPS-address.

I have specified my keystore and truststore through `-Djavax.net.ssl-properties`.
When I use those stores with a very simple (non-TomEE) command line program which does an `HTTP-GET` request, it works fine, I get a response, no worries, so the issue doesn't seem to be with my stores.

With SOAP UI and the same stores, it still works, I get a response from the endpoint, so it's not the endpoint, it's me.

Now, when TomEE tries to create a Dispatcher, I get "bad certificate" and I don't understand why. I have SSL-Debugging enabled, it tells me it uses the stores I specified and still no dice. Is there something sneaky going on?

This is the exception thrown: `http-bio-8080-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate`

Trying to add my own SSLSocketFactory to the dispatcher has no result:
`disp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", new SoapSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory));`

Also, setting the default on HTTP connections doesn't work, this is all just bypassed it seems: `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new SoapSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory));`

Comment: Okay guys, I switched to Wildfly 8.0 (prev JBoss) and the problem went away. So clearly, it's a TomEE+ issue.

Comment: What class is `Dispatcher`? Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: It's javax.xml.ws.Dispatch

Comment: Gotcha... probably going to need the full stack trace and the code you wrote to get to the bottom of this though

Comment: I fixed it in Wildfly by using `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory` (dropping the internal part)